# How can I create an apk file from xml and java files which i have got after extracting from the app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, apk, android-install-apk

I have to create an apk file from the files that I have extracted from the same app using reverse engineering. Can someone help me to create the app using the xml and java files that i have got. ?

Comment: Did you actually "reverse engineer" the code, or simply unpack someone else's binary?

Comment: Reverse engineer @durbnpoisn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to copy it to an IDE like Android Studio. Simply create a new Project and add the files on their directories.

The app might have some dependencies that you can only add using gradle build. So re-zipping the app and giving it the apk extension might not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If these are extracted from a `.apk` file, just zip the root/base/top folder and rename it from `example.zip` to `example.apk`.

Otherwise use your IDE to generate an apk file.